# Why can de-noising diffusion models be sampled with Gaussian distributions?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, gaussian-process, central-limit-theorem, random-walk

In de-noising diffusion models [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) the latent is typically sampled with a unit normal distribution, and then the sample (e.g. image) is generated by iteratively removing noise during the backwards process.  Whereas in the diffusion (forward) process, the random Gaussian latent is predicted by iteratively adding Gaussian noise to the original image.  So is the implication that this iterative addition of gaussian noise to the image (in the forward process) eventually leads back to an approximately unit gaussian distribution for the resulting random variable?

In other words, assuming the sample/image distribution itself is not Gaussian, is there some reason to expect that adding a large number of gaussian distributions to an initial non-Gaussian random variable would lead back to a unit Gaussian distribution, at least in the limit of this Gaussian random walk?

[Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) by Jonathan Ho, Ajay Jain, Pieter Abbeel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compute the distribution of the noisy sample after $t$ iterations of the forward process in closed form, using equation 4 in the paper:

$$q(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_0) = \mathcal N(\mathbf{x}_t|\sqrt{\bar \alpha_t} \mathbf{x}_0, (1 - \bar \alpha_t)\mathbf I)$$

where $\mathbf{x}_0$ is the original sample, $\bar \alpha_t = \prod_{i=1}^t (1 - \beta_t)$, and $\beta_t \in (0,1)$ is the fixed variance level in the $t$-th iteration of the forward process.

In DDPM, the number of iterations in the forward process is fixed to $T=1000$, and the variance levels $\beta_1, \dots, \beta_T$ increase linearly from $10^{-4}$ to $0.02$, which means that $\bar \alpha_t$ is (approximately) 0. Therefore, the latent distribution $q(\mathbf{x}_T|\mathbf{x}_0)$ is a unit Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is not immediately obvious (great question). In order to provide a response, and aiming for a complete and integrated answer, we first define the DDPM forward procedure, and subsequently discuss how its derivation reveals why the final target distribution is indeed a Gaussian distribution.

We are reminded that for DDPM diffusion models, the forward procedure details a Markovian process for corrupting the data distribution

$q(x_{t} \vert x_{t-1}) \: = \mathcal{N} \big( \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_t}} \cdot x_{t-1} , \: (1 \: - \: \alpha_t) \cdot \mathcal{I} \: \big)$

whereby the $\smash[b]{\alpha_t}$ hyperparameter is defined as a function of another hyperparameter $\alpha_{t}=1-\beta_{t}$. The algorithm adds step-wise deformations to the data distribution by injecting Gaussian noise at each time step. The solution to the analytical form of the final target distribution $x_{t=T}$ is found in a previous [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/641837/294109).

$x_{t} \: = \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{\bar{\alpha_{t}}}} \cdot x_{0} \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{1 \: - \: \bar{\alpha_{t}}}} \cdot \epsilon_{t}$

given by $\bar{\alpha_{t}} = \prod_{t=1}^T \: \alpha_{t}$, and each noise random variable $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathcal{I})$. It is the inspection of this derivation that reveals the use of a special property of Gaussian distributions: The sum of two Gaussian random variables is another Gaussian random variable, with the mean being the sum of the means and the variance being the sum of the variances. Since each noise addition step in the forward diffusion model is assumed to be Gaussian, this property ensures that, after multiple iterations, the overall distribution remains Gaussian. From the perspective of the Central Limit Theorem (CLT), each step of adding noise can be seen as adding an independent random variable to the system. When you apply many such noise addition steps (assuming they are independent and identically distributed), the result, according to the CLT, tends toward a Gaussian distribution.

The following excerpts are taken from my book on variational inference. Learn more on the topic by visiting https://www.thevariationalbook.com/