# How is the variance for a diffusion kernel derived for a diffusion model?

Tags: neural-networks, variance, computer-vision, generative-models, diffusion

So I'm watching [this video tutorial from CVPR this year on diffusion models](https://youtu.be/cS6JQpEY9cs?t=835), and I am confused by the variance term in the distribution on the left on the video. I understand that in the forward process, we can track intermediate distributions

$$q(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_{t-1}) = N(\mathbf{x}_t;\sqrt{1-\beta_t}\mathbf{x}_{t-1},\beta_t\mathbf{I})$$

And that the joint distributions of all the intermediate steps conditioned on the input is given by

$$q(\mathbf{x}_{1:T}|\mathbf{x}_{0}) = \prod_{t=1}^Tq(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_{t-1}).$$

If we define $\bar{\alpha} = \prod_{s = 1}^t(1 - \beta_t),$ then we are supposed to derive the diffusion kernel

$$q(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_{0}) = N(\mathbf{x}_t;\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}}\mathbf{x}_0,(1 - \bar{\alpha}_t)\mathbf{I})$$

I can definitely see why the mean is what it is, but I'm having a hard time seeing where we get the variance from. How is the variance of $(1 - \bar{\alpha}_t)\mathbf{I}$ derived?

Answer (score 1):

There are many styles and flavors of diffusion models. For a forward Markovian inference process popularized by Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models ([DDPM](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239)) , the solution is to apply the reparameterization trick recursively.

$x_{t} \: = \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_{t}}} \cdot x_{t-1} \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{1-\alpha_{t}}} \cdot \epsilon_{t-1}
\\ \\ =
\sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_{t}}} \cdot \big( \sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_{t-1}}} \cdot x_{t-2} \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{1-\alpha_{t-1}}} \cdot \epsilon_{t-2} \big) \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{1-\alpha_t}} \cdot \epsilon_{t-1}
\\ \\ =
\sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_{t}\alpha_{t-1}}} \cdot x_{t-2} \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_{t} \: - \: \alpha_{t}\alpha_{t-1}}} \cdot \epsilon_{t-2} \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{1 \: - \: \alpha_{t}}} \cdot \epsilon_{t-1}
\\ \\ =
\sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_{t}\alpha_{t-1}}} \cdot x_{t-2} \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{  \sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_{t} \: - \: \alpha_{t}\alpha_{t-1}}}^2 \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{1 - \alpha_{t}}}^2 }} \cdot \epsilon_{t-2}
\\ \\ =
\sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_{t}\alpha_{t-1}}} \cdot x_{t-2} \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{\alpha_{t} \: - \: \alpha_{t}\alpha_{t-1} \: + \: 1 \: - \: \alpha_{t}}} \cdot \epsilon_{t-2}
\\ \\ =
\ldots
\\ \\ =
\sqrt{\smash[b]{ \prod_{t=1}^T \: \alpha_{t}}} \cdot x_{0} \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{ 1 \: - \: \prod_{t=1}^T \: \alpha_{t}}} \cdot \epsilon_{t}
\\ \\ =
\sqrt{\smash[b]{\bar{\alpha_{t}}}} \cdot x_{0} \: + \: \sqrt{\smash[b]{1 \: - \: \bar{\alpha_{t}}}} \cdot \epsilon_{t}$

given by $\bar{\alpha_{t}} = \prod_{t=1}^T \: \alpha_{t}$, and each noise random variable $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathcal{I})$. The final equation applies the mathematical property governing the mean of two independent Gaussian random variables as the sum of the two means, and likewise, the variance as the sum of the two variances.

Notice the dependence of the result on the initial input $x_{0}$. As $t \to \text{T}$, the signal-to-noise (SNR) decreases in value, and the ratio approaches zero such that $\bar{\alpha_t} \approx 0$ until the final target distribution is equivalent to $\mathcal{N}(0,\mathcal{I})$. Furthermore, keep in mind these parameters could be directly learned or indirectly optimized for using SNR.

The following excerpts are taken from my book on variational inference. Learn more on the topic by visiting https://www.thevariationalbook.com/

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for hours on this question too until I finally found useful resource here: https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2021-07-11-diffusion-models/

The key is to use re-parametrization trick and combine the sum of the noise as a new gaussian distribution.
Hope this helps!